# Rails mail.deliver_later is not working, while mail.deliver is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In my `spkrs_controller` I have a private method:

```
def send_spkr_remove_mail
  mail = SpkrMailer.with(spkr: @spkr, editing_spkr: current_user, tlk: @spkr.tlk).removed
  mail.deliver
end
```

This works successfully, but when I change this to:

```
def send_spkr_remove_mail
  mail = SpkrMailer.with(spkr: @spkr, editing_spkr: current_user, tlk: @spkr.tlk).removed
  mail.deliver_later
end
```

The message does not send.

The method is called in this method:

```
def remove
  send_spkr_remove_mail
  @spkr.destroy
  redirect_to show_tlk_path(@spkr.tlk)
end
```

(I need to trigger `send_spkr_remove_mail` before `@spkr.destroy` otherwise there is no `@spkr` instance to use in the mail constructor.)

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Thank you

Comment: I think, in ur first case mail.deliver executes instantly and it has access to the spkr instance. But when u do mail.deliver_later it doesnt executes instantly and before it executes you destroy the instance of spkr so now whenever it gets executed it tries to access the spkr instance which it no longer has because it was destroyed earlier.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitAgarwal, yes I thought so too.